# Google Vision Scanning PDF417

Tags: android

I am a bit baffled and I cannot figure out what the issue is

I have a Samsung A2Core where the scanning works perfectly without problems, it takes 2-3 seconds but it works

Here is my code

```
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.cameraView);

    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.PDF417)
            .build();

    int width=getIntent().getIntExtra("width",1600);
    int height=getIntent().getIntExtra("height",1024);

    CameraSource.Builder builder = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(width, height)
            .setRequestedFps(15)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true);

    cameraSource = builder.build();
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(this);
```

On the samsung A2 Core I am using the defaults 1600 and 1024.
Other Phone I tested is a Samsung A21s

The barcode I am trying to scan looks like this[image: SA Drivers]

Libraries I am using

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Comment: You should probably blur/remove fingerprint and parts of code

Comment: Could you please add failure handlers and post some logs?

Comment: I've once suffered frequent issues with vision library on different devices, which was solved by clearing Play Services cache, it sometimes malfunctions and doesn't downloading necessary model. You can try to replace it with standalone version, which contains all the necessary data and doesn't rely on Play Services

Comment: Not sure how to add failure handles but I believe the standalone version would work better, I have not used it before, do you know where I can find it ?

Comment: Follow this tutorial, pick "Bundled" version: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android Also note, that docs say "V2 model is faster and more accurate.
Adds support for broken PDF417 start/stop pattern detection, improving recall by 10.5%" So you will definitely benefit using it

Comment: Thank you, I will test this out and revert back

Comment: Just a question, do you use the CameraX for the camerafeed ?

Comment: Nope, good old Camera1 api. But that shouldn't really make a difference

Comment: @DmytroRostopira I actually forgot to respond to this but I did come right with your suggestions